# Estimating the embedded memory size of numerical routines

Tags: embedded, cross-compiling, 68000

There is only one other similar question [here](http://www.example.com/) but I'm trying to use a different way to estimate the size requirements.

I am trying to compare how two numerical routines would perform on a 68k. The embedded size and execution speed are the metrics that I need to quantify.

Details about the routines: One contains a lot of complex mathematical operations like exponentiation. The other is an approximated version and has only additions and multiplications.

For comparing the execution times, I am simply using the wall clock time for both routines on my computer.

To compare memory size I made a cross compiler and generated the binary code with static linking of the math library. The size of the binaries would be a good measure of the memory requirements on the embedded system, right?

**EDIT** I am using crosstool-NG for building the compiler. When I use `m68k-unknown-uclinux-uclibc-gcc` the codes compile. However, when I use `m68k-unknown-elf-gcc` I get an error `fatal error: math.h: No such file or directory`. I thought that the library part referred to the target and compilation is done using the libraries on the host machine.

Comment: By size, do you mean code size (ROM), or memory usage (RAM), or both?  The first is easily found by inspecting the linker's map file.  The second is significantly more involved if you are using any sort of dynamic allocation.

Comment: @OregonJim. Thanks for your comment. Actually, I am not very sure but I think both are affected by using the simplified numerical routine instead of the complex one. There is a lot of other stuff going on (reading input, computing the model based control, setting the actuator signals). My task is to take one part of the model and simplify it mathematically

Comment: @OregonJim Could you please elaborate on the linker map. I'm a numerical analysis guy with very little background in embedded systems

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: @yaska, the map file produced by the linker (you may have to enable it with a switch) shows you the code size of the various segments of your program, as well as the static data size.  It will not help you figure out any dynamically allocated memory, however.

Comment: Also, make sure you are only linking in those functions that are actually used in your code, and not the whole math library ("smart" linking).  Read up on the compiler's optimization switches as well - some favor size, while others favor speed.

Comment: One thing to consider here is that the standard library math.h functions often work with floating point, so if you use those, you'll naturally need much more memory.

Answer (score 1):

One of the possibilities may be:

- Size: Use the objdump to get the information about your object file, it provides a lot of useful information, such as the symbols and their address. Another way is generating the map file, it contains where the objects and symbols are mapped into memory (RAM and ROM, but not the dynamic allocations). These links could help you: [objdump](https://linux.die.net/man/1/m68k-linux-gnu-objdump) [map](https://linux.die.net/man/1/m68k-linux-gnu-ld)
- Execution time: Given that it has to be calculated at runtime, IMO you have two options: an internal uC timer or a toggle pin (and an oscilloscope). I prefer the second option, it is easier from the implementation point of view, and the accuracy is better than a timer (furthermore, it needs less instructions)

Edit: regarding your edit, try adding the path to the compilation command (or makefile), such as `-I[yourPath]`

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer. I did not understand how I could use the information from objdump to differentiate ROM and RAM memory requirements

Comment: @yaska the reference manual provides the memory map, which explains how the memory is distributed (and their addresses, so you are able to know if it is ram or rom).